# Google spreadsheets in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

how do you store the collected values ​​in an array?

I can already collect values, but I don't know how to store them

```
function onGAPILoad() {
gapi.client.init({
  // Don't pass client nor scope as these will init auth2, which we don't want
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
}).then(function () {
  console.log('gapi initialized')
  chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
    gapi.auth.setToken({
      'access_token': token,
    });
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
      spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
      majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
        ranges: [
            "A2:A"
        ]

    }).then(function(values) {
         console.log(values)
    });
  })

}, function(error) {
  console.log('error', error)
});
}
```

Response in console:

```
{result: {…}, body: "{↵  "spreadsheetId": "1f99uX3zCeqF5Nlu4LJVQ_uEd9T4…↵          "BC639"↵        ]↵      ]↵    }↵  ]↵}↵", headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: null}result: {spreadsheetId: "1f99uX3zCeqF5Nlu4LJVQ_uEd9T4Mao8r32eAHsijnjw", valueRanges: Array(1)}spreadsheetId: "1f99uX3zCeqF5Nlu4LJVQ_uEd9T4Mao8r32eAHsijnjw"valueRanges: [{…}]0: {range: "main!A2:A1000", majorDimension: "COLUMNS", values: Array(1)}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: constructor: ƒ Object()__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: "hasOwnProperty"__proto__: ƒ ()[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toString: ƒ toString()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()body: "{↵  "spreadsheetId": "1f99uX3zCeqF5Nlu4LJVQ_uEd9T4Mao8r32eAHsijnjw",↵  "valueRanges": [↵    {↵      "range": "main!A2:A1000",↵      "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",↵      "values": [↵        [↵          "TC123",↵          "BC632",↵          "TC124",↵          "BC633",↵          "TC125",↵          "BC634",↵          "TC126",↵          "BC635",↵          "TC127",↵          "BC636",↵          "TC128",↵          "BC637",↵          "TC129",↵          "BC638",↵          "TC130",↵          "BC639"↵        ]↵      ]↵    }↵  ]↵}↵"headers: cache-control: "private"content-encoding: "gzip"content-length: "230"content-type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"date: "Sat, 29 Feb 2020 18:16:00 GMT"server: "ESF"vary: "Origin, X-Origin, Referer"__proto__: Objectstatus: 200statusText: null__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you please share an example of the values response? Is it already an array? Or is it an object?

Comment: Hello, I added what the console returns me to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet()`.
- You want to retrieve the values as an array.
- You have already been able to retrieve the values using Sheets API with `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the retrieved values are retrieved as an array in `gapi.client.init()`.

#### Modified script:

```
unction onGAPILoad() {
  gapi.client.init({
    // Don't pass client nor scope as these will init auth2, which we don't want
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('gapi initialized')
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
      gapi.auth.setToken({
        'access_token': token,
      });
      gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
        spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
        majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
          ranges: ["A2:A"]
      }).then(function(values) {
        const ar = values.result.valueRanges[0].values;  // <--- Modified
        console.log(ar);  // <--- Modified
      });
    })
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  });
}
```

- You can retrieve the values with `const ar = values.result.valueRanges[0].values`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the retrieved values are sent to other function as the arguments.

#### Modified script:

```
function onGAPILoad() {
  gapi.client.init({
    // Don't pass client nor scope as these will init auth2, which we don't want
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('gapi initialized')
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
      gapi.auth.setToken({
        'access_token': token,
      });
      gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
        spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
        majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
          ranges: ["A2:A"]
      }).then(function(values) {
        getValues(values);
      });
    })
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  });
}

function getValues(e) {
  const values = e.result.valueRanges[0].values;
  console.log(values);
}
```

- You can retrieve the values at the function of `getValues`.

### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, the retrieved values can be used in the function of `onGAPILoad`.

#### Modified script:

```
async function onGAPILoad() {
  const getValues = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gapi.client.init({
        // Don't pass client nor scope as these will init auth2, which we don't want
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      }).then(function () {
        console.log('gapi initialized')
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
          gapi.auth.setToken({
            'access_token': token,
          });
          gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
            spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
            majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
              ranges: ["A2:A"]
          }).then(function(values) {
            resolve(values);
          });
        })
      }, function(error) {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }

  const res = await getValues().catch(e => console.log(e));
  const values = res.result.valueRanges[0].values;
  console.log(values);
}
```

- You can retrieve the values at the last line.

### Note:

- In your request, only one range is used. So I used `res.result.valueRanges[0].values`. When you want to use multiple ranges, please retrieve the values from `res.result.valueRanges` using the loop.

### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

If I misunderstood your question and these were not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: thank you very much, how do i check if a value is contained within the list?

Comment: @Felipe Gbur Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you use the multiple ranges for values.batchGet, how about `const values = res.result.valueRanges.map(r => r.values)` for retrieving values? But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So if this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: My application has the function to collect or value on the Ex TC123 page and then check if this value is contained within my spreadsheet, but I still don't know how to check

Comment: @Felipe Gbur Thank you for replying. About your new question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60480166/7108653 , if this is the same with replying, I answered it just now. Could you please confirm it?